# how to get inner HTML with jquery 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code (jquery 2.0.3):

```
alert($('<p>test <b>me</b></p>').filter('p').get(0).html());
```

Chrome says:

```
Cannot call method 'html' of undefined
```

What's wrong?

Btw, I'm expecting `test <b>me</b>`.

ps. My problem is that I'm running this from XSLT, not HTML. But thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: This doesn't work in jQuery 1.9 or 1.10 either. Or even 1.4.4. What you have is a logic error.

Comment: the `.get()` method returns the actual element at the given position; the return value is **not** a jQuery object, in other words.

Comment: `.get(0)` returns a DOM element.  You probably want `.eq(0)`.

Comment: You can remove `.filter('p').get(0)` and get what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `.get(0)` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/NMhQW/

```
alert($('<p>test <b>me</b></p>').filter('p').html());
```

Comment: or replace `get(0)` with `eq(0)`

Comment: The `.filter('p')` isn't necessary.

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure what the context of his use was, so I figured I'd leave it in. e.g. multiple <p>'s, etc.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall thanks, but this code doesn't work when I'm running it from XSLT instead of HTML, but that seems to be another story

Comment: XSLT? Havn't heard that since Umbracos early days ;} And of course, it's not HTML so I doubt the jQuery method would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use `.get(0)` then you would get back the actual DOM element, not the jQuery object. So you'd have to use standard DOM stuff.. in this case

```
$('<p>test <b>me</b></p>').filter('p').get(0).innerHTML;
```

Otherwise if you wanted to keep it all jQuery, you could say

```
// based on the .get(0) I'm assuming you want the first matched element?
$('<p>test <b>me</b></p>').filter('p').eq(0).html();
```

And to grab every paragraph's html

```
$('<p>test <b>me</b></p>').filter('p').html();
```